# loading the web page after scrolling

Tags: web, scroll, loading

I have a huge web page (text) and it takes lot of time to load in the browser. So I want it to be loaded in steps and not at time. Initially it should load some x lines or whatever space available on the screen. When I start scrolling it should load next x lines. For a huge web page, while loading the page, browse hangs for a while, So I want to avoid this condition. Please help.

Comment: you're trying to implement similar to that of 9gag and facebook right?

Comment: yes, like facebook, but I need it very simple for text only.